# measuring a generated wave frequency using ICU - Atmega32

Tags: timer, embedded, atmega32

I'm trying to use the ATMega32 Input Capture Unit in the following manner:

I have a wave generated using TIMER0 (through OC0 pin) (XTAL=8MHz, prescaler =1024, CTC mode, OCR0=244, giving ~32Hz).  I am then trying to capture this wave using TIMER1 (through ICP pin) (XTAL=8MHz, prescaler=1024, normal mode, resulting in ~7812.5 Hz)

The code snippet provides more details.

The problem that I have only result of 0.

**

### MODIFIED.

**
thanks alot @clifford , 
according to the below code ,it works ,but :

1- there's a little error  (results aren't accurate).

2- when i change my equation

from

```
        count=(capture2+(captOVf*65536))-capture1;

           to   
   count=capture2-capture1;
```

i get garbage displayed on the LCD .

very sorry for the bad question formatting .

```
typedef enum{
    CAPTURE1,
    CAPTURE2,
    WAIT
}timer_states_t;

volatile timer_states_t flag= WAIT;
volatile u8 x,y,captOVf,TOVfs=0;
volatile u16 capture1,capture2;

void setup_pins(){

    SET_BIT(DDRB,3); //SET OC0 pin as output
    CLEAR_BIT(DDRD,6); //set ICP pin as input
    SET_BIT(PORTD,6);  //set ICP pin pullup resistance

}

//Timer0 Configurations / wave generator .
void timer0_init(){
    OCR0=244;
    TCCR0=0x1D; //ctc , 1024 , toggle OC0 pin on compare match ;
}

//Timer1 Configurations / capturer .
void timer1_init(){
    TCCR1A=0x00; // Timer1 , normal mode, no on compare output ,
    TCCR1B=0x45; // prescaler 1024, Input capture edge as rising .
    SET_BIT(TIMSK,TICIE1); // enable input capture interrupt .
    SET_BIT(TIMSK,TOIE1); //enable timer1 overflow interrupt .
    CLEAR_BIT(ACSR,ACIC);  //disable Analog comparator .
    SET_BIT(SREG,7); //GLOOBAL ITERRUPT

}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect){
    TOVfs++;

}

ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect){
    switch(flag){
    case CAPTURE1:
        //capture1=ICR1;
        x=ICR1L;
        y=ICR1H;
        capture1=x | (y<<8);
        TOVfs=0;
        flag=CAPTURE2;
        break;

    case CAPTURE2:
        //capture2=ICR1;
        x=ICR1L;
        y=ICR1H;
        capture2=x | (y<<8);
        flag=WAIT;
        captOVf=TOVfs;
        break;
    }
}
int main(){

setup_pins();
timer0_init();
timer1_init();
LCD_init();

unsigned long count  ;
u8* countString ;

while(1){
    flag=CAPTURE1;

    while(flag != WAIT);

        count=(capture2+(captOVf*65536))-capture1;
        itoa(count,countString,10);
        LCD_send_string("count:");
        LCD_send_string(countString);
        _delay_ms(500);
        LCD_send_cmd(lcd_Clear);

    }
}
```

Comment: You say the result is not accurate, without revealing the actual result.  What are you getting, what did you expect, and why - show your working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing ever modifies `capture1` or `capture2` which are themselves unitialised.

```
capture1 = x | (y<<8);
...
capture2 = x | (y<<8);
```

perhaps? `temp1`, and `temp2` appear to serve no purpose; being set in the ISR and not referenced elsewhere.

Given that TIMER2 count will be about 244 for a single 32Hz cycle, is the overflow counter not unnecessary?  Simply reset the TIMER1 count at CAPTURE1 and get the count at CAPTURE2, removing the arithmetic and one of the `capture` variables.

All shared variables need to be declared `volatile`, all non shared variables need not be global.

Comment: check the modified question again , please.

Comment: @AliK. Now it is not the same question, ideally you would post a new question. Especially since this answer has been accepted. You should not modify the question to include advice from answers since it renders the existing answers nonsense. SO is a Q&A not a discussion forum. You can include a link to this question if that is useful for context.  There is a far simpler solution.